# Best way of updating a table with SSIS using a OLE DB Command

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis, updates

I have the next query

```
insert into tabla_A (value_1, value_2, value_3)
select table_B.value_1, table_B.value_2, table_B.value_3
from tabla_A right join (table_C left join table_D on table_C.value1 = table_D.value1)
on table_A.value_1 = table_B.value_1
where table_A is null
```

As you can see, I have several tables involved in this query, and the thing is that table_B, table_C, table_D belong to an Oracle Database and Table_A is located in a SQL server.

What do you thing is the best way to face this query?, I mean by using the less quantity of merge join tasks, and using more the SQL statement. Also taking into account that source and destination are the same (table_A)

Comment: Would it be possible to extract the values that you need from oracle and store them in a staging table on your sql server?  Then you could perform the statement above as you have it.  In this way, you would be able to avoid the merge join or using linked servers.

Comment: Hi. That is the problem, I can not create any staging table

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is somewhere between. If your table is not that large and your Oracle Server is not busy with other tasks, it is good to just transfer single A table to it and exec query there (assuming the fact your DW is also on Oracle)If you have huge table to join with and your SSIS server has enough RAM to handle joins without disk caching (this is tunable via dataflow buffer size), then you should perform intermediate joins on server, and the most hard one on SSIS server. 
Also, you should avoid using

```
insert into...
```

in SSIS solutions, because you have its **insert bulk** cheat. Use oledb/odbc destination!